# Regular expression to find all text inside of { } including spaces and newlines

Tags: python, regex

I spent many hours and exhausted for this. I know regex is a very strong tool but it is too difficult to me. Please help me.
I want to extract a json string from html pages. This is a example of the nested json.

```
<script>

            window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {
       "properties":"ASSET_HOST", "https"
:"//asom","recaptcha":"ABCD", "aaa": {"b":"C", "D":"E"}
            };

        </script >
```

And I wrote a regex expression like this to extract all text rounded by curly braces {}.

```
parttern = '(\{.*\s*\});\s*<'
```

But it returns only parts of string.

```
{"b":"C", "D":"E"}
            }
```

Could you advice me how I should write a regex expression to extract all string rounded by {} please?

Comment: You'll need a recursive approach which `re` does not offer - use `regex` instead.

Comment: If you want to parse json, then instead of the `re` module, have you considered using the `json` module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but in order to have the outer curly braces as well, you'll need a recursive approach which only works with the newer `regex` module. Consider

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'\{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))*\}')


junk = """
<script>

            window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {
       "properties":"ASSET_HOST", "https"
:"//asom","recaptcha":"ABCD", "aaa": {"b":"C", "D":"E"}
            };

        </script >
"""

for match in rx.finditer(junk):
    print(match.group(0))
```

Which yields

```
{
       "properties":"ASSET_HOST", "https"
:"//asom","recaptcha":"ABCD", "aaa": {"b":"C", "D":"E"}
            }
```

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CS2V6c/1).

---

Obligatory warning: "parsing" stuff like this with regular expressions is usually not the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. you are my hero.  . Still I can't understand the expression you gave. However, It works very well !

Comment: @WoochanCho Hint: `(?R)` tries to match the entire regex recursively. See https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/default/